# How to convert dates in CompuLaw Vision database to DateTime

Tags: sql, date, datetime, integer

I need to convert integer dates in a (CompuLaw) database to DateTime format.  However, I can't tell what integers correspond to what dates.

CompuLaw Vision says it stores dates as Julian values, but that's not accurate.  Dates in the last 5 or so years are stored as values between 146500 and 151646.  That's not Julian, which stores 1/1/1900 as 2415021.

Answer (score 0):

This produces the correct dates in limited testing:

> SELECT DATEADD(DAY, @CompuLaw_Date - 109573, '1900/01/01');